# Simplifying resistors in a circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

The task is to simplify the following system of resistors. 
I'm not looking for solutions, rather, I'm looking to understand what to look for in order to draw an equivalent circuit.

The picture is a bit cut off, but opposite of B is A.

[image]

What's bothering me the most are the marked spots:

[image]

What exactly happens there? I can't seem to wrap my head around the nodes with 2-3 three branches.

Comment: I'd start by re-drawing this in more familiar form with vertical and horizontal lines only. Remember that all points on "wires" that are not interrupted by resistances are on the same potential , so you can freely move around these parts. For instance you can move the marked nodes into each other making it a node with five connectors, or you can also split nodes (by connecting the wires at a different spot). For instance from the node at the top (4 connectors) you could make  two nodes of three connectors each. If you do this, you should be able to see that some resistors can be replaced.

Comment: You can construct the dual of the circuit, it is already easy to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit diagram has been drawn to confuse you; which it has?
The two circles are part of one node.
The two resistors to the right are in parallel.
The cell and series resistor are in parallel with the other resistor on the left.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that you can transform a star circuit with three resistances into an equivalent triangular circuit with three different resistors. Thus it simplifies your circuit considerably if you transform the inner star circuit into a triangular circuit so that you have 3 resistances in parallel with the 3 branches of the outer triangle circuit.

This is called a Y-\Delta transform and can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform).

Comment: @RonaldB - One of the star branches is a short circuit. Thus, as Farcher has pointed out in his correct answer, you need not even the transform to reduce the inner star circuit to a triangular one.